# Why Doesn't Intercept Url Work?

Tags: spring, spring-security

This is my Spring Security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />

    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"  />
.......
```

I add this: `<intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"` to avoid to enter in that section.. but I can enter into monitoring after loggin as "normal" user...

Why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of `<intercept-url .../>` does matter. As the new `intercept-url pattern="/monitoring"` comes after `pattern="/**"` it it ignored because all URLs for monitoring have already been processed by `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />`.

You should write :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/monitoring" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"  />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

As a general rule `intercept-url pattern="/**"` must **always** be last